# Building a solution which contains a windows service and a windows forms project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild

I have a solution which contains a windows service and a windows forms project. Is it possible to build the solution and have the output from both project in one folder ? The ouput folder should contain the windows service exe and also the win forms exe files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `copy` in both projects build events.

Like this

```
copy /Y $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)output_file_you_want_to_copy C:\some_dest_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Give both projects the same OutputPath with a fully qualified path that includes $(OutDir).

You'll need to examine the contents of your project files in a text editor.  By default the OutputPath is defined across multiple property groups that change this value based on the $(Configuration) and $(Platform) values.

Your end result should have a common "OutputPath" located within both project files.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AssemblyName>WebService</AssemblyName>
<RootNameSpace>Project.WebService</RootNameSpace>
<ProjectGuid>{deadbeef-dead-beef-dead-beefdeadbeef}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputPath>$(OutDir)\$(Configuration).$(Platform)\ProjectDropFolder\</OutputPath>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```