# Compile a VS2012 C# project that contains both windows form and service

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012, service, installation

Visual Studio 2012, C#:

I am developing an application that part of it must be run as service and the other part as windows form.
I have created a single project, added windows form and added service, I have also created service Installer and Service Process Installer.

When I compile I just see the exe file that refers to my windows form application.

How I can compile properly a solution that contains both service and windows form application?

I saw a question regarding "[Building a solution which contains a windows service and a windows forms project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060458/building-a-solution-which-contains-a-windows-service-and-a-windows-forms-project)". But that refers to different solutions each contain either windows form application or windows service, this differs than my question.

Comment: Do you really mean that you've created a single *project*, or that you've created a single *solution*? You seem to be using the words interchangably, but they're different things. I would suggest creating a single solution, but with multiple projects - one for the service, one for the GUI etc. They may all depend on a class library project which contains common code.

Comment: Tnx, I understood I shall not combine projects in a single solution. and how I can make a class library project and how I can refer my projects to it?

Comment: Well have you read the documentation for class libraries? Searching for "msdn class library project" would be a good start...

Comment: Actually yes, after I read your guide, I created a class library and I got a DLL file as output. It works fine for specific Logging module of my solution. But I wonder how to convert all that related classes (that I have created and tested in my windows form project) into DLLs!

Comment: Well you shouldn't be thinking of one DLL per class... you may well be fine to just move all the common classes into a single DLL.

Comment: I am performing several tests and I feel I am reaching what I want... I will test the rest tomorrow and update results here.

Comment: I successfully merged my 2 solutions as projects in a single solution containing my last 2 projects (service and form) and a new CLASS project. the only remained issue is accessing my MDF file (standalone database). Functioning dataset is now located in my class project as well as the MDF file. My windows form projects works well with it but the service don't... I am working on it to find specific root of problem. I will update result here. I may ask further questions regarding this if I won't find the answer somewhere. Thank You.

Comment: No result! I can't access my database using my service. I created an additional TEST winform project copied the exact codes my service uses on start, it worked! But it doesn't work as a service!...    Note that every other functions of this service are working except dealing with MDF database file.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what you saw. It could be a permissions issue, it could be that you're assuming a working directory inappropriately (try hard-coding the absolute path), it could be something else...

Comment: Yes, sorry for vague description. Actually I wouldn't understand the reason that time. After investigation I found an access violation to my MDF file. I can't access it simultaneously via the GUI process and service process. If I open it with any of them, I shall close that process THEN open it up with another.            The error is "Unhandled exception has occured in your application..... Cannot open database <MDF FILE ADDRESS> requested by the login. The login failed."

Comment: I found the reason. When I run service I am running it with a LocalService account, I am running my GUI app with logged in user. I started service with logged in user the GUI and service got able to share the MDF database. I think I shall find a way to put a password for my MDF file and modify the connection string in order to avoid logging to database with Windows Authentication. It would resolve the problem.              By the way it will not related to this topic. If I won't be able to find the solution I will start a new discussion and point its link here, then you can help me there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a solution with two projects, one with the Windows Form app a other with windows service. (Don't add references from one project to another, if you have common code in both projects, extract those common code to a dll project a reference it from the others.)

Comment: Thank you. could you please more explain on: (Don't add references from one project to another, if you have common code in both projects, extract those common code to a dll project a reference it from the others.) ?

Comment: If you have duplicate code in both Windows forms and Windows service, you must extract those code to a new class (for example Bussines.cs) and add it to new dll proyect. Then referecen this ddl in both proyects (forms and service), replacing all code with calls to class Bussines.  (If it apply)